# What's the file extension?

Tags: code-golf, string

Your challenge is to find the file extension of a provided filename:

```
hi.txt -> txt or .txt
carrot.meme -> meme or .meme
lol (undefined behavior)
what..is..this..file -> file or .file
.bashrc -> bashrc or .bashrc
T00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h -> h0wC[]h or .h0wC[]h
agent.000 -> 000 or .000
```

**You must get the text from the last `.`  or after the last `.` to the end of the string.** The first capturing group match of the regular expression `/\.([^.]+)$/` works, and so does splitting the input on `.`s and returning the last one.

The file name will always contain at least one `.`, but it may contain multiple `.`. (see examples)

The input will always match [`^[.a-zA-Z0-9^!\[\]{}@$%+=]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/KW4sF3/2).

Comment: Please consider using the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) in the future to get feedback on your challenges before posting them to the main site.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12432/59376 - Got this idea from your challenge.

Comment: @carusocomputing nice challenge!

Comment: why the negative votes? Is this challenge "exceedingly trivial" or so ?

Comment: @AbelTom edit history would suggest downvotes were for the lack of specifications in the first draft of this question.

Comment: @Arjun the downvote count seems to be slowly increasing. I have no idea why.

Comment: Are we allowed to take the length of the string as input?

Answer (score 16):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 5 bytes

```
.*\.
```

Replaces everything and a dot with nothing at all.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nFaPH9f9/RmpOTr5eeX5RTopeSWpxiV5WQbpeakUqAA)

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), 19 bytes

Returns the full filename when there's no file extension. I suppose this is an acceptable *undefined behavior*.

```js
let f =

s=>s.split`.`.pop()

console.log(f("hi.txt"))               // -> txt
console.log(f("carrot.meme"))          // -> meme
console.log(f("lol"))                  // -> undefined behavior
console.log(f("what..is..this..file")) // -> file
console.log(f("T00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h")) // -> h0wC[]h
console.log(f(".bashrc")) // -> bashrc
```

Comment: The point of undefined behavior is that anything goes. Although, nasal demons, while still undefined behavior, might fail the "no malicious programs" clause.

Answer (score 10):

## POSIX Shell, 13

```
echo ${1##*.}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#NYzNCsIwEITvPsWwrRchC54F3yW0GxJIs5IsKEifPY1C5/DB/DBBK0yaLb4JUgHFxPYxAi2@VjXeZJPhsubBd/TGnBqzxR9DykIPrHrB0KumYgF0bXBPEObv@bz/@yYG5zCfaZcl6ljdp@nGe1@1SD8A).

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, <strike>13</strike> 22 bytes

*Edit: Not sure how I missed the `".bashrc"` test case. Thanks to Artyer for keeping me honest.*

```
FileExtension["a"<>#]&
```

If the input matches `\.[^.]+`, then `FileExtension` just returns the empty string, so we prepend the letter `a`. In any other case, prepending `a` doesn't affect output of `FileExtension`.

Comment: A Mathematica builtin...no surprise.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there weren't any mathematica builtins for any question possible

Comment: I don't have access to Mathematica, but I would suspect that `.ext` would result in nothing, which failes for `.bashrc` needing to output `bashrc` (It fails in [Mathics](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#@x9QlJlXEu2WmZPqWlGSmlecmZ8XraSXlFicUZSsFBv7/z8A "Mathics – TIO Nexus"))

Comment: [Apparently it works](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37457009#37457009)

Comment: Mathematica just needs to meta built-ins `Create Built-in XXXXXXXX`.

Comment: @Artyer You are correct.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Do you mean the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/)? Just get your code approved there, and you can refer to it while golfing!

Answer (score 8):

## c function, 21

- 1 byte saved thanks to @Dennis.
- 3 bytes saved thanks to @JohanduToit.
- 2 bytes saved thanks to @Neil.
- 1 byte saved thanks to @algmyr.

```c
f(s){s=rindex(s,46);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#XZDBboMwDIbvPIUVqVJCWehh2oV1L9JxiLKkWIJQxWarVvHsLMA00HxIfv2Of33O5CWpB50jhg93l1Q8v6hqnDAwdAYDyFmZeLUF2D4Qg21MhDw5nwoeGaRaHXbE1pCjSw3n385cokHNdxbF5lgTY8@6c53b2WUp2r4VRVI5WDOkKDBA7urN0DLk5Rbw1RjWGklrbubTY@vE0h6r5ZqhscoW7fuYtkhMpwoQXkESfrveyz9gBSX89y6nWqn0/nhUu11u6ZfYS3EgeHqDA72HhLvNYF3APgPnjBVrRYmOhxgSSDZOPw).

Comment: If you're ok with using legacy POSIX functions you could use `rindex` to save a byte.

Comment: @algmyr Sure, it works fine on TIO, so I'll use it.  I'd never heard of `rindex()` before - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
'.¡¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@ud2jhoSX//5dnJJbo6WUW6@mVZIDItMycVAA) or [Try All Tests](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/K@ud2jhoSX/K5UO77dSULLX@Z@RqVdSUcKVnFhUlF@il5uam8qVk5/DVZ6RWKKnl1msp1eSASLTMnNSufSSEoszipK5QgwMfB3yjL0TA6L0MgzKnaNjMwA)

```
'.   # Push '.'
  ¡  # Split on occurrences of '.'
   ¤ # Tail
```

Comment: What? I've never seen a split occurences in [the wiki](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands). Edit: Now I found it!

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

2 bytes of code, +1 for the `h` flag.

```
q.
```

#### Explanation:

```
q.       Split the input by `.`
   -h    Return the last item
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@1@o9/@/UnlGYomeXmaxnl5JBohMy8xJVdLNAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 21 Bytes

```php
<?=pathinfo($argn,4);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVcrI1CupKFGy5rK3@29jb1uQWJKRmZeWrwGW1jHRtP7/HwA)

is a shorter expression for

```
<?=pathinfo($argn)[extension];
```

[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

## PHP, 27 Bytes

```php
<?=end(explode(".",$argn));
```

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVcrI1CupKFGy5rK3@29jb5ual6KRWlGQk5@SqqGkp6QDVqWpaf3/PwA)

### PHP <7.0, 26 Bytes

```php
<?=end(split("\.",$argn));
```

deprecated [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

Comment: Are you counting a trailing newline for the first one? It should be 27 bytes, not 28.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Thank You .I have count after copy and paste from the split version a `\`

Comment: The `pathinfo()` based one could be `<?=pathinfo($argn,4);`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Neo4j Cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher), 24 bytes

```
return split($i,".")[-1]
```

Input is in a param (`i`), probably the only way for cypher to take input. Pretty straightforward. [Cypher has never been used on PPCG before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cypher)

Answer (score 4):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 1397 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 1 l 4 r 1 l.[a]Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.Switch to plan "a".[b]Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 l 1 l.[c]Go to Fueler Up:n.Go to Joyless Park:n 2 r.Go to Narrow Path Park:w 1 r 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:w 1 l 1 r 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.Pickup a passenger going to Joyless Park.'.' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:s.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.Go to Crime Lab:n 1 r 2 r 2 l.Switch to plan "c" if no one is waiting.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 5 l.[d]Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.Switch to plan "e" if no one is waiting.Switch to plan "d".[e]Go to Joyless Park:e 1 r 3 l.Switch to plan "f" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Fueler Up:w 1 l.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 4 l.Switch to plan "e".[f]Go to Narrow Path Park:w 1 r 3 l.[g]Switch to plan "h" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to KonKat's:e 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 2 l.Switch to plan "g".[h]Go to KonKat's:e 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:s 3 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTLboMwEPyVVS65WWqaXji2VSs1VRsprXpAHAxZsBVqI9sR5eupCYYQAnkdbGutfczsjm3oHy/LVwlGwlJqA59xzCP0criD1C5VnWTJo802AwoZ1RpFggoSyUVSRT0xmcFqiwWps7S2J5p4mLs8Pg1OpfqgSskcltQwu6mNy9i/3iXeg@uXxbasPckq5yZilUeWUgGTcAI8BiFBCgSuIafc2PJHfnRC/DCoc38xhEcaYhpzzVAVLQDLKHI@L1tMLZfvzBMO0ZssUtS6gTyzYEb45DvE9@caXUSpBd3wra3OoGbn4hX/RXin4UmvLmoyJdNOj4Aa@FHcoJpqeMZMGofl8NLTF8JwRBrb6WXmqPQHEo0MblQjD9V41sFt2j0U0UU67APGC5W2tkrDYEAz2MqiHxKPpL7hce11m3de0wDV@SBF4sfBWVX7SdCPZDcwWEixoGaqHcbGrPt0TeQAuyHFJZYdC64u1vlGyfHHqm1Har2UZc6oIYRrQgyr9pin@A8)

Taxi doesn't have a reverse function so this ballooned pretty quickly. The logic is:

1. Break the string into characters
2. Reverse the array
3. Iterate through each until a period is found, storing each in a FIFO array
4. Empty the array (because there's only one LIFO array available)
5. Dump the FIFO array into the LIFO array
6. Concatenate the LIFO array and output

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>5</s>, 3 bytes

Since more of this answer is unprintable than printable, here is a hexdump:

```
00000000: cd81 ae                                  ...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@491DjoXX//2dk6pVUlHAlJxYV5Zfo5abmpnLl5OdwlWcklujpZRbr6ZVkgMi0zJxUAA)

This uses [Jan Dvorak's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120937/31716), it just happens to be a more efficient encoding of it.

Explanation:

```
Í       " Remove all occurrences of:
 0x81   "   Anything (greedy)
     ®  "   Followed by a dot
```

Old solution:

```
$T.d|
```

Comment: Explanation please?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Done

Comment: Wait `®` means followed by a dot? Lol that's weird.

Answer (score 3):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), 12 bytes

```
$(suffix $1)
```

Not using a builtin, 27 bytes:

```
$(lastword $(subst ., ,$1))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 10 bytes

```
@echo %~x1
```

Strangely competitive for once.

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 5 bytes

```
$F.d0
```

Explanation: find last `.` in line, delete everything before it

Another, longer, but in my opinion still interesting approach with 9 bytes (notice the trailing new line)

```
d/.*\./e
```

This one works similarly, 5 bytes (again, trailing new line):

```
d?\.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 22 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Split('.').Last()
```

Implicit `using System.Linq;` FTW!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctNawIxEIDhc/MrggibgB0CvflFQVoorlBUKLR6mMasGdidlWR0BfG3bymll/c5vT4/@kz965n9NEsiPo70n3Nd6Znu82yeYXOqSUwBhYUSsxjbT1TVpoA@anPBpEkT6zeGdcDDtn3hg7H/044La9XDRyIJJXEww8GN7uOd3CpD9j6wkz4SyFWUx5RagSY0QXURBYAygMTfVlQHBd@YY/Jq69zqmZ@W@P4J0XWLr31UeAws4Jz7AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <del>34</del> 26 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```
(Read-Host).Split('.')[-1]
```

Takes input from STDIN. Actually managed to golf it down shorter than the built-in.

## PowerShell, 20 bytes

```
($args-split'.')[-1]
```

Takes input from commandline arguments. Big thanks to @mazzy again!

## PowerShell (with built-in), 36 bytes

```
[IO.Path]::GetExtension((Read-Host))
```

Comment: you can save some bytes. try this `($args-split'.')[-1]` see [About Automatic Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 45 bytes

```forth
: f begin 1 -1 d+ s" ."search 0= until type ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETvfsWQq3RJ9WZRBI8iePCkeIht2gTStCRbql9fU6yX2Xm7s1N3gU3W1POYph1qvHRjPXJkOao1ogCJqFUoDeQeg2frwJ9eo0jpHptq6H9MAsgOEKmiDChW6dNY4jcL9DOUKoSOqdWtXjauc4sbjWIiG4nYzFpb9w/RS0UTyoVuUl6OfntW1zsZOZ4eT7NcVKM9k5Qy8fQF)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f              \ start a new word definition
  begin          \ start an indefinite loop
    1 -1 d+      \ remove the first character from the string
    s" ."search  \ find the length and starting address of the first substring that starts with '.'
    0=           \ check if '.' was found in the string
  until          \ end the loop if not
  type           \ output the result
;                \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 29 bytes

```
print(input().split(".")[-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```rust
|p|p.extension().or(p.file_stem())
```

Usable as a `fn(&std::path::Path) -> Option<&std::ffi::OsStr>`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5NCsIwEIX3PUXsQiagOcD4s3NdwQOUVic0YJOYmWJFPXstulB04@Yx8L75eKljGaxXbeU8aHXNjiTKovUwZTkgxkoaxO2Yer4uorjgl6/GWodY8E7SWq2GW7xFQ72Q5xEBbUKCaKw7UslCLWg9LLKOST1/AyN23vWflk0vi6xipiQlnSZgfxYgejpD3jgjveRaz9QutARfa8Y7hbasL0IMdf5C9X9qU1fcpP2/7jc@@u/DAw)

Answer (score 2):

## JS (ES6), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
x=>/\.([^.]+)$/.exec(x)[1]
```

-1 byte thanks to Shaggy

```js
document.querySelector('pre').innerText = (x=>/\.([^.]+)$/.exec(x)[1])("example.txt")
```

```html
<input oninput = "document.querySelector('pre').innerText = (x=>x.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)[1])(this.value)" value = "example.txt">
<pre></pre>
```

Alternate, 29 bytes:

```
x=>(y=x.split`.`)[y.length-1]
```

Comment: Rulw seem allow `x=>/\.[^.]+$/.exec(x)`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```
s=>s.slice(s.lastIndexOf`.`)
```

Spec change in comments removes the need for `+1`.

-3 bytes thanks to nderscore

Comment: -3 with `slice` and template string execution: `s=>s.slice(s.lastIndexOf\`.\`)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṣ”.Ṫ
```

A monadic link taking the file name and returning the extension with no leading `.`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w5@JHDXP1Hu5c9f////KMxBI9vcxiPb2SDBCZlpmTCgA)**

#### How?

Literally does what was asked...

```
ṣ”.Ṫ - Main link: list of characters, f
 ”.  - literal '.'
ṣ    - split f at occurrences of '.'
   Ṫ - tail (get the last chunk)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 8 bytes

```
s:.*\.::
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@19spacVo2dl9f9/RqZeSUUJV3JiUVF@iV5uam4qV05@Dld5RmKJnl5msZ5eSQaITMvMSQUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 85 bytes

Go is... troublesome.

```
import(."fmt"
."os"
."strings")
func main(){s:=Split(Args[1],".");Print(s[len(s)-1])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#K0hMzk5MT1XITczM@5@ZW5BfVKKhp5SWW6LEpaeUXwwii0uKMvPSi5U0udJK85LBKjU0q4utbIMLcjJLNByL0oujDWN1lPSUNK0DgEpLNIqjc1LzNIo1dQ1jNWv///@fkalXUlECAA)

A sample of parentheses from the code:

```
()(){([])([()])}
```

Comment: `()(){([])([()])}` — is it a valid Brain-Flak?

Comment: @eush77 It's technically *valid* Brain-Flak, since it will run without errors, but it doesn't do anything interesting/useful. It's either just the literal `2` with no instructions/commands or anything or an infinite loop that continuously allocates more memory, depending on input.

Comment: Using `filepath.Ext` will save you a few bites

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES5), 38 bytes

```js
function(s){return s.split(".").pop()}
```

Comment: Just so you know, the downvote was cast automatically by the Community user when your answer was edited. [I consider this a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276269/170332).

Comment: plz fix that if you can!

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 57 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(#1=reverse(subseq #2=(#1# s)0(search"."#2#))))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/clisp#DcixDkBADADQX5Hr0i4NdqNgQQ6D8dCEBOEafv944wt4@e2cEXd3TItDJYQk8/KKV0F9JpU7gjT7FyKlGFWcn1fDBlKgn2mHnnlsBsvc9baqC@Yyt7khCuED) (added some bytes to call this anonymous function and display returned string)

#### Explanation

```
(#1=reverse ...)     ;reverse is now accessible with #1# - saves 1 byte. I 
                     ;also need to reverse output of function inside to 
                     ;get extension in correct order
#2=(#1# s)           ;reverse of input string is now accessible with #2#
(search"."#2#)       ;I take reversed string and search for "." to get position of 
                     ;first instance of "." in string from the end of it
(subseq ... 0 ...)   ;get part of reversed string, 
                     ;starting from first character and ending just 
                     ;before first occurance of "."
                     ;this gives reversed extension
```

I get substring of reversed string, starting from 0, ending on this

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>33</s> 41 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Split('.').Last();
```

Edit as suggested:

```cs
using System.Linq;a=>a.Split('.').Last();
```

Comment: You need to include `using Sytem.Linq;` into your byte count

Comment: And also `a=>a.Split('.').Last();` implicit return is shorter

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks for suggested fixes, still new to this :)

Comment: I'm surprised this is longer than my solution using `Path`...

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>52</s> 27 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll(".*\\.","")
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY5PSwMxEMXv@ymGnHbFDgGPRVE8Skuhnmx7mKZpk5pNlmTaKrKffc1KrrKXYf783ntzpivNQqf9@fA5KEcpwYKs/6kArGcdj6Q0LMcRYM3R@hOoujSpmed9X@WSmNgqWIKHRxjS7Clh1J3L4hfnaoF32y2KeyGaYT7i3WXvMl5U12AP0ObUYrzZUVMSvxPrFsOFscsXdr72qGphLPIXi@bvgf8xRTEGxla3epJ1wU0yN0OMaBMim7EerZs2xj0lE9Uk9y7l4tk/vNHqA428vW52ZlJDJ@0ZpZSF7Kt@@AU)

Replace everything before the last dot (and the dot itself) with nothing.

This is shorter than using split (`s->s.split("\\.")[s.split("\\.").length-1];`) or substring (`s->s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('.'));`).

Answer (score 2):

## Gema, 3 characters

```
*.=
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '*.=' <<< 'what..is..this..file'
file
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
46&YbO)
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=46%26YbO%29&inputs=%27what..is..this..file%27&version=19.11.0)!

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as string
46      % ASCII for '.'
&Yb     % Split the input string at the '.' characters
O)      % Retrieve just the last part
        % Implicitly print the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## Awk, <s>14</s> 13 characters

(<s>10</s> 9 characters code + 4 characters command line option.)

```awk
{$0=$NF}1
```

Thanks to:

- [Robert Benson](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45724/robert-benson) for spotting the unnecessary semicolon (-1 character)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ awk -F. '{$0=$NF}1' <<< $'hi.txt\ncarrot.meme\nlol\nwhat..is..this..file\n.bashrc\nT00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h'
txt
meme
lol
file
bashrc
h0wC[]h
```

Comment: You don't need the `;`. and just FYI, `awk '{$0=$NF}1`  works, no command line option needed. Oh... I must be tired.  I see what you did there.  You do need the command line option.

Comment: Thank you, @RobertBenson. I have no idea why I put that `;` there.

Comment: If there is always a character after the last `.`, then `$0=$NF` is enough, with `-F.` command line option.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>53</s> 30 bytes

Replaces everything upto the last `.` with the empty string `''`.

Double parenthesis to select only the first return value of `gsub`.

Any golfing tips are welcome, I'm rusty in lua...

```lua
print(((...):gsub('.*%.','')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@19QlJlXoqGhoaenp2mVXlyapKGup6Wqp66jrq6pqfn///@kxDwg1EtMSkxOLEnVS61IBQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 6 bytes

**Solution:**

```
*|"."\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X6tGSU8pRqk8I7FETy@zWE@vJANEpmXmpCr9/w8A)

**Examples:**

```
*|"."\"whats.up.txt"
"txt"
  *|"."\"T00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h"
"h0wC[]h"
```

**Explanation:**

Split `\` the input on `"."`, reverse `|` this list, and then take the first `*` one. K is interpreted right-to-left:

```
*|"."\ / the solution
  "."\ / "." split (\),
 |     / reverse
*      / first
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 21 bytes

```
x=>x.split('.').pop()
```

**Explanation:**

This code takes `x.txt` and turns it into a array. The last element of the array is the file type. This code uses the `pop` function to remove the last element. In the process, the `pop` function returns the last element.

Comment: +Dennis, I have turned it into a arrow function. Does this comply with the rules?

Comment: Yes, it is fine now. :) By the way, StackExchange uses @ to ping people, not +.

Comment: Save 2 bytes with ``x=>x.split`.`.pop()``.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 46 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard and Scrooble*

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1].split('.')[-1])
```

EDIT: I fixed the code, and the filename is a command-line argument

Comment: Welcome to the site! This doesn't appear to [work](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4spgr0RZI6iUWpZdFG8TqFRfkZJZoaHIVFGXmlWgkRuek5mkkasZq/v//X6kktbhEr6SiRAkA), so you should either fix, or delete this answer.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4spgr0RZI6iUWpZdFG8bqFRfkZJZoqOupa3IVFGXmlWgkRuek5mkkauoaxmr@//@/JLW4RK@kogQA) works for 54

Comment: To get the last item of a list you can use `-1` as the index instead of `len(a)-1`.  You could also probably change your input format to reduce the number of bytes.

Comment: Adding to WW's suggestion: if you use `-1` rather than `len(a)-1`, you no longer need the assignment and can save quite a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [FORTRAN 90](http://CHARACTER(99)F,L;READ*,F;DO%20I=1,LEN(F);IF(F(I:I)=='.')L=F(I:LEN(F));ENDDO;PRINT*,L;END), 87 bytes

```
CHARACTER(99)F,L
READ*,F;DO I=1,LEN(F)
IF(F(I:I)=='.')L=F(I:LEN(F))
ENDDO
PRINT*,L
END
```

A shorter version in FORTRAN 90.

---

## [FORTRAN 77](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/index.html), 137 bytes

```
      PROGRAMC;IMPLICITCHARACTER*99(F)
      READ*,F;DOI=LEN(F),1,-1;IF(F(I:I).EQ.'.')THEN
      PRINT*,F(I:LEN(F));EXIT;ENDIF;ENDDO;END
```

There is no space in `PROGRAM C`, nor in `IMPLICIT CHARACTER`. It works (!) in `gfortran`, but I'm not sure it works in others compilers. The program takes input from `stdin` and outputs the extension *with* the period. The total length of the file name is limited by 99.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 45 bytes

```
INPUT S$@L
E$=POP(S$)+E$ON"."==E$[0]GOTO@L?E$
```

Outputs extension with the period.

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 17 bytes

```kotlin
split(".").last()
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
split(".").last()
```

### Test

```kotlin
data class Test(val input: String, val output: String)

val test = listOf(
        Test("hi.txt", "txt"),
        Test("carrot.meme", "meme"),
        Test("what..is..this..file", "file"),
        Test(".bashrc", "bashrc"),
        Test("T00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h", "h0wC[]h"),
        Test("agent.000", "000")
)

fun String.f() =
split(".").last()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for ((i, o) in test) {
        if (o != i.f()) {
            throw AssertionError()
        }
    }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##ZZDBSsQwEIbvfYqxpwRKKHhbrLgsnkQU3JPiIa5NM9gmSzK1iuyz1062K4udQ_5h5ptM8n94atGN2bsmDbtWxwjbOpL41C2g2_e0gicK6JoCuOR7OqvJLOMiTQNQQYuRHozIYI50T25R0RflBeQssvjX3ukQPKmu7mpmki6gwWpSCqNSZPk02CY66YJWbzrasGNgzhbItizvb9zlnX58VrYcNi-vlvFTuuB1UztSZVkyxSKz6e-md7MRyggJ1Rj3LfIDcqkmJ0nIMTGdRid0aOIK1iHo76vj0LWEn7TH-ABCYAFeTp4nO08tDjQgPFxUgLzmvMNBNvgB1jHWgdC728nOIOQfcsiO52H8BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 bytes

```
òdt.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///CmlBK9//9z8vOz9XIT9fLzcir10vJLi/SSKktSiwE)

Recursively delete everything up to, but not including the next `.`

Answer (score 2):

### C++, 73 bytes

I'm a bit surprised that no one tried C++, since it's an easy one :

```cpp
#include<string>
auto e=[](std::string s){return s.substr(s.rfind(46));};
```

And the code to test ( may have to `iostream`, `initializer_list`, and `exception` ) :

```cpp
std::initializer_list<std::string> test{
    "hi.txt", // .txt
    "carrot.meme", // .meme
    "lol", // invalid string position
    "what..is..this..file", // .file
    ".bashrc", // .bashrc
    "T00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h", // .h0wC[]h
    "agent.000" // .000
};

for (const auto& a : test) {
    try {
        std::cout << e(a) << '\n';
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range& r) {
        std::cout << "out of range exception : " << r.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

And, as you may expect, like compilers, if there's undefined behavior, there's no undefined behavior. If there's no file extension, the function will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception, as said in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), <s>1315</s> 1287 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 8 0 0
0 1 0 1 2 0 0
1 1 1 1 9 0 0
0 2 0 1 3 0 0
1 2 1 1 a 0 0
0 3 0 1 4 0 0
1 3 1 1 b 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0
1 4 1 1 c 0 0
0 5 0 1 6 0 0
1 5 1 1 d 0 0
0 6 0 1 7 0 0
1 6 1 1 e 0 0
0 7 0 1 f 0 0
1 7 1 1 0 0 0
0 8 0 1 9 0 0
1 8 1 1 9 0 0
0 9 0 1 a 0 0
1 9 1 1 a 0 0
0 a 0 1 b 0 0
1 a 1 1 b 0 0
0 b 0 1 c 0 0
1 b 1 1 c 0 0
0 c 0 1 d 0 0
1 c 1 1 d 0 0
0 d 0 1 e 0 0
1 d 1 1 e 0 0
0 e 0 1 0 0 0
1 e 1 1 0 0 0
0 f 0 0 g 0 0
1 f 1 0 g 0 0
0 g 0 0 h 0 0
1 g 1 0 p 0 0
0 h 0 0 q 0 0
1 h 1 0 i 0 0
0 i 0 0 r 0 0
1 i 1 0 j 0 0
0 j 0 0 s 0 0
1 j 1 0 k 0 0
0 k 0 0 l 0 0
1 k 1 0 t 0 0
0 l 0 0 u 0 0
1 l 1 0 m 0 0
0 m 0 0 n 0 0
1 m 1 0 v 0 0
0 n 0 0 o 0 0
1 n 1 0 g 0 0
0 p 0 0 q 0 0
1 p 1 0 q 0 0
0 q 0 0 r 0 0
1 q 1 0 r 0 0
0 r 0 0 s 0 0
1 r 1 0 s 0 0
0 s 0 0 t 0 0
1 s 1 0 t 0 0
0 t 0 0 u 0 0
1 t 1 0 u 0 0
0 u 0 0 f 0 0
1 u 1 0 f 0 0
0 o 0 1 w 0 0
1 o 1 1 w 0 0
0 w 0 1 x 0 0
1 w 1 1 E 0 0
0 x 0 1 y 0 0
1 x 1 1 F 0 0
0 y 0 1 z 0 0
1 y 1 1 G 0 0
0 z 0 1 A 0 0
1 z 1 1 H 0 0
0 A 0 1 B 0 0
1 A 1 1 I 0 0
0 B 0 1 C 0 0
1 B 1 1 J 0 0
0 C 0 1 D 0 0
1 C 1 1 K 0 0
0 D 0 1 D 0 1
1 D 1 1 w 1 0
0 E 0 1 F 0 0
1 E 1 1 F 0 0
0 F 0 1 G 0 0
1 F 1 1 G 0 0
0 G 0 1 H 0 0
1 G 1 1 H 0 0
0 H 0 1 I 0 0
1 H 1 1 I 0 0
0 I 0 1 J 0 0
1 I 1 1 J 0 0
0 J 0 1 K 0 0
1 J 1 1 K 0 0
0 K 0 1 w 1 0
1 K 1 1 w 1 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdJZjoJAFEbhd1dRKyDi7KMjqKsARcFZxEbdvK3Hv21vKuFa9cWEk6LYxWX5eFTda/nP9ZwVX7877Kruva/J3qsrq2F1WQ2LZHWsIatjsayBNWUNbC5rYi1ZE1vIWlhb1sISWRtbytp/PVgH68o6pqGLRbKuaYiwWBaZhhiby2LTMMcWsrlpWGCJbGEaElf9vPXr9LuBMreSLZGVjOlS2Qo7yjh1J1mKZTKmy2UZtpYx3Vm2xjYyptvKNlgh49RdZFtsJ2O6vWyH/cg4dQfZ3vQdTcMRO8lOpuGE5bLcNOTYWcbUW/vP3XdDYRoK7CJjfr6zC7aUHbi/Unbg/kpZiV1lJTaSXbGb7IqNZTfsLrthgeyO9WR3LJT1sL6sh01kfWwg62NT2QAbygbYTDb8mF95zXefj42wsf43Mg1jLJCNTUOAhbLANITYRBaahgk2lU1MwxSbyaamYaY78rHZf8PjUaZR4XnZ2fOK9PVcZtvkFw)

Wow, this is big.

Comment: Wow this is incredible!

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 50 bytes

```
{v
 >~:a`!#v_
--2*86:$<:u-10_v#
02-u0}>:#,_@   >00
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v7qMS8GuzioxQVG5LJ5LV9dIy8LMSsXGqlTX0CC@TJnLwEi31KDWzkpZJ95BQUHBzsDg//8QAwNfhzxj78SAKL0Mg3Ln6NgMLgA)

Puts string onto stack, then iterates through it in reverse, putting each new character onto new stack.  Once a `.` is encountered, discard original stack and output new stack in `0gnirts` format.

Answer (score 2):

## [33 v1.0](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 13 bytes

*The behaviour of the `y` operator was changed in v1.1, so this program no longer works*

Gets the file name passed as an argument and prints the extension (without leading '.') to standard output.

```
1bt'.'ywmcbtp
```

Explanation:

```
1b            (Gets the second item in argv, the filename input)
  t'.'y       (Splits that by '.')
       wmcb   (Gets the last element in the list)
           tp (Prints to standard output)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 45 bytes

```
,[>,]>+[[-]++[<->------]<---<[->+>+<<]>]>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOJ9ZOOzpaN1ZbO9pG104XDGJtgIRNtK6dtp22jU2sXaxdtJ5d7P//IQYGvg55xt6JAVF6GQblztGxGQA)

Answer (score 2):

### [Setanta](https://try-setanta.ie/), <s>66</s> 34 bytes

```
gniomh(s){toradh roinn@s(".")[-1]}
```

[Try it here!](https://try-setanta.ie/editor/EhEKBlNjcmlwdBCAgICgpZKTCg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [6 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
Ê^!⁺╔d
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=OiEiLiI6fQ==&input=aGkudHh0CndoYXQuLmlzLi50aGlzLi5maWxlClQwME1AbjNLYVBaLmgwd0NbXWg=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `:!".":}`

```
    _ Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
  :! Split on
    "." String containing a period
:} Tail
```

Answer (score 2):

### [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes (SBCS)

```apl
⊃∘⌽'.'∘≠⊆⊢
```

-7 bytes after Bubbler's suggestion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FX86OOGY969qrrqYMYnQsedbU96lr0P@1R24RHvX1A@UPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4BgNle@dxZWTqlVSUcIHZyYlFRfklermpuakQgZz8HAijPCOxRE8vs1hPryQDRKZl5kCVhBgY@DrkGXsnBkTpZRiUO0fHZkAkEtNT80r0DAwMAA)

### [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes (SBCS)

```apl
⊃⌽'.'(1↓¨,⊂⍨⊣=,)⍞
```

#### Explanation

```apl
⊃⌽'.'(1↓¨,⊂⍨⊣=,)⍞
                ⍞ string input
            ⊣=,)  get characters, evaluate if they are equal to the left arg '.'
         ,⊂⍨      enclose each part after a dot
  '.'(1↓¨         drop each dot in the strings
 ⌽                reverse the split string array
⊃                 take the first value
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdIe3/o67mRz171fXUNQwftU0@tELnUVfTo94Vj7oW2@poPuqdB1L2P40rI1OvpKKEK40rObGoKL9ELzc1NxXIy8nPAZLlGYklenqZxXp6JRkgMi0zByQZYmDg65Bn7J0YEKWXYVDuHB2bARRNTE/NK9EzMDAAAA)

Comment: Including the dot is allowed (so you don't need `1↓¨`), but then, you can use [`≠⊆⊢`](https://aplcart.info/?q=split%20separator#) idiom to split the words at dots, excluding dots.

Comment: Then the tacit `⊃∘⌽'.'∘≠⊆⊢` is one byte shorter than full program `⊃⌽'.'(≠⊆⊢)⍞`.

Comment: interesting. I'll try it out. How do it get it to work on TIO?

Comment: [No different from other function submissions.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FX86OOGY969qrrqYMYnQsedbU96lr0P@1R24RHvX1A@UPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4BgNle@dxZWTqlVSUcIHZyYlFRfklermpuakQgZz8HAijPCOxRE8vs1hPryQDRKZl5kCVhBgY@DrkGXsnBkTpZRiUO0fHZkAkEtNT80r0DAwMAA)

Comment: Or equally long: `⊃∘⌽⎕NPARTS`

Answer (score 2):

**Python3 (32 bytes)**

```
f=input()
print(f[f.rfind('.'):])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRCMtOk2vKC0zL0VDXU9d0ypW8///jEy9kooSAA)

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might like to include a link to [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRCMtOk2vKC0zL0VDXU9d0ypW8///jEy9kooSAA "Python 3 – Try It Online") in your answer. TIO is widely used here because it's quite handy: not only does it let other people try out your code, it also creates pre-formatted CGCC submissions for you.

Answer (score 2):

## 8086 Assembly (NASM) + DOS, 262 bytes source, 50 bytes assembled

I'm pretty new to assembly, but I thought I'd give this a try.
This is a full DOS program, not just a snippet.

```
section .bss
b resb 256
org 256
section .text
mov byte[b],254
mov ah,10
mov dx,b
int 33
mov bh,0
mov bl,[b+1]
add bx,b+2
mov bp,bx
l:sub bx,1
cmp byte[bx],46
jne l
mov byte[bx],10
p:mov ah,2
mov dl,[bx]
int 33
add bx,1
cmp bx,bp
jb p
int 32
```

Essentially, it reads a line of text into a buffer, seeks the end,
then seeks backwards until it reaches a `.`. Then it just prints
the rest of the string from that point on. I wasn't able to use
DOS's built-in print function, though, since that uses `$` as
the end-of-string character, which the prompt says is a valid
character for the extension itself.

Here is the hexdump of the assembled binary:

```
00000000  c6 06 34 01 fe 88 e4 ba  34 01 cd 21 b7 00 8a 1e
00000010  35 01 81 c3 36 01 89 dd  83 eb 01 80 3f 2e 75 f8
00000020  c6 07 0a b4 02 8a 17 cd  21 83 c3 01 39 eb 72 f3
00000030  cd 20
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
\.€t
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C.%E2%82%ACt&inputs=agent.000&header=&footer=) ([Test cases!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C.%E2%82%ACt&inputs=hi.txt%0Alol%0Acarrot.meme%0Awhat..is..this..file%0A.bashrc%0AT00M%40n3KaPZ.h0wC%5B%5Dh%0Aagent.000&header=%40f%3A1%7C&footer=%2C%3B%0A%0A%E2%96%A1%28n%20%40f%3B%29))

Splits on spaces and outputs the tail.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
p;char*f(char*s){for(;*s;)p=*s++^46?p:s;return p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5Ni8IwEAbgs/srwoDQtDoElEUMxYU9iuBhT35BNqQmYGNIsiiIv72rlQoq1BwyM294mMj@Vsqqclxq4dMiqUugp2LvE54GTl2ehizbDD8nbhy4V/HPW@L4uSqFsQk9fXScNzYWCXT7o0DynHTDykKPXBJtMB4jkIdDewTuMeVtXgrv9xFLVSp49E3U7g9aREQTEKO@3oXZKah93b31@CuC9hJe/988tPsfxmZfdjAV8wVqdvherjXcfDO1e7FVNiJjDJ73N9nFn6t/)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 45 bytes skipping `return`

```c
p;char*f(char*s){for(;*s;)p=*s++^46?p:s;s=p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5Ra8IwEAfwZ/cpwoHQtHoElCGG4mCPQ9jDnuYUstA2ARtDLqAgfvbMdXTgBjUPubt/@HHR00brlLzURoW8zrpC/FwfQiZzktyXORXFbv648kuSVHp5Sa2yLuPnh5EP1sU6g/F0Qaws2Zg@HEzYNTEW4ykCuzl8wuA35nLIaxXCIWJbtRXc@j4a9kejIqIlxGi@79ruK@h81931@KnIBA3//98/DPs3IdZPbvaiXt/RiOPzZmvgx/fTsFdN5SIKIeDv/j67@kv6Ag)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 24 bytes by ceilingcat

```c
#define f(s)rindex(s,46)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5NC8IwDAbgs/6KEhmssIWCIoIMBI8iePDkx6F23VpwVdbCBuJvn3NSQYXZQ0je8JCKOBeiaUapzLSRJAstLbVJZR3aaDKlTcG1CeltOLi2sctCCOKZJUlCAnswELUAlEZXOyAfj0YE3jGd93nBy/LisJCFhE/vo35fKe4QtUV06lkzfZbQ@a776/HErSoF/P7fL/r9lrH1woxXfLNDxarl/qjg5f3U73kujUPGGHzf91nr780D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.split('.')[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFWsV1yQk1mioa6nrhmtaxj7v6AoM69EIU1DPSNTr6SiRF2TCy6SnFhUlF@il5uam4osnJOfg8wtz0gs0dPLLNbTK8kAkWmZOUDl/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 84 bytes

Includes +2 for `-rc`

```
(()){{}([((((()()()){}())()){}{}){}]({}<>)<>)({()(<{}>)}{})}{}{{}}<>{}{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hoalZXV2rEa0BApogqAnkakLo6logEatRXWtjpwlEGtVAeZvqWjtNkAwQA3UCpYA0TAmQ/P8/I1MvNzU39b9uUTIA)

```
# Push 1 to start the loop
(())

# Start loop
{{}

  # If TOS == 46 i.e. '.'
  ([((((()()()){}())()){}{}){}]({}<>)<>)({()(<{}>)}{})
  # ^------------------------^ ^-------^ 
  #           This is 46         Also, copy TOS to other stack

# End loop after the first '.'
}{}

# Delete everything from this stack
{{}}

# Delete the '.' that got copied
<>{}

# Copy everything back to reverse it to the correct order
{({}<>)<>}<>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
q'. o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@1@orqeQ//@/Um5pTklmQU6qXkp@SbFecn5@jhIA)

## Explanation

```
 q'. o
Uq'. o
Uq'.    # Split the input at "."
     o # Return the last item
```

Comment: When you only need to return the last item of an array, you can use `o` in place of `gJ`. (Learned that trick from @obarakon a while back)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)

```
⊟⪪Ｓ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/@oa/6jVave79ms9/9/YnFKml5afr5eUmIREFcBAA)

### Explanation

```
⊟      Pop
  ⪪ .  Split on "."
   Ｓ  Next input as string
       Implicit print of value
```

Comment: Can't you use `⊟x` instead of `§x±¹`?

Answer (score 1):

## jq, <s>15</s> 14 characters

(<s>11</s> 10 characters code + 4 characters command line options.)

```
./"."|last
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -Rr './"."|last' <<< 'what..is..this..file'
file
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/s/xhwN4TRSJj)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 24 bytes

```
@(x)strsplit(x,'.'){end}
```

Creates an anonymous function named `ans` which can accept a string as input

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/JoPlJJ)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>47</s> <s>34</s> 27 bytes

```c#
System.IO.Path.GetExtension
```

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @totallyhuman.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX3@YqhqxY0P1B1I1oExYIL1yFNbSCdgc7UB9Jvj9WAZ3Phviwve0KKI3u8weXF4vpSKRsMM9TqrWCGxYi3cCffwMl4zIufncIv@xHtimWYPxaQdAMtrGM61Iezro10unKye4pD9oSx/M@3hEzB6evgxR09urzNs86FQPpBQ2iyokjlSU3xAw)

Comment: Since it's a built in I think you don't need the lambda. `System.IO.Path.GetExtension`.

Comment: @milk Of course I do, that's just a method, it won't return `.ext` from `file.ext` because with just a method there's no way of passing the `file.ext` in.

Comment: [This is all you have to do.](https://tio.run/##NY3NCsIwEITveYqlpxQ0L1D1IiqCYsGD55CmNpDuQnfrD9Jnj7XFuQzMMN84XraElHoOeIfrm8W3hVIuWmYo1UfBKBYrwcGDQgVnG1DnUzyXP@17dCuWbmQsYPYN1LBOM9AcL6a00piDl91LPHIgLNJ/vSVkit7cuiD@FNDrWmeNj5HMk7pYZXleTFeDGtIX "C# (Mono C# compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @totallyhuman Thanks, saved another byte by dropping the trailing semi colon to.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
ecz\.
```

[try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ecz%5C.&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=hi.txt%0Acarrot.meme%0Awhat..is..this..file%0A.bashrc%0AT00M%40n3KaPZ.h0wC%5B%5Dh)

Answer (score 1):

## REXX 53

```
parse value reverse(arg(1)) with e "." 
say reverse(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 35 bytes

```c#
s=>s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("."));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cs-mono#NY1NCsMgFIT3nuKRlULxAmmyKRQKKS1k0bVV0wpWwaf9oeTs1kQ6m4FvhpmExt1g/GDUj5YQaQUinMmXQBFGEY2EpzcKjsI4ylZcw0X75OQWYygbG6jewwRdxq5HPqZrZRT5IDAenNLv00Qb3jDW5v/Izjv0VvNLMFEPxmlaKndtrecvH6xayuvjTOb8Aw)

Answer (score 1):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Laikoni*

```
r=reverse
r.fst.span(/='.').r
```

self-explanatory

Comment: `takeWhile` can be shortened to `fst.span`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>77</s> <s>60</s> 52 bytes

```c
char*f(char*s){for(s+=strlen(s);*--s-46;);return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5NSwMxEAbgs/6KMFBIajMEFBHCgtCjCB48@XGIIdsEummZGalQ@tvXurJCFdYcMjNveJhEu4qx72MONG/1UNjs2w1pvmhYaJ2qZuPn1rK9uvbGU5J3qor9oe9Cqdrsz8@2VKq0Gmb2hlXTqBm/VFioY5ILyoeAOjlmoeAnNn7Kx0C0EexSl@DUj9G03@UgiIURJX/dbVknGPzQ/evxLXCmCH//Pz5M@0fn7m/r5V14eMLsdsvn1wzffpymfVilKuicg9/7x@zoD/0n)

-17 bytes from Jonathan Frech

-8 bytes by removing `i` and doing arithmetic on `s` directly

Ungolfed (same strategy):

```c
char *extension(char *original) {
    original = original + strlen(original);
    while(original[0] != '.') --original;
    return original;
}
```

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##hdBNawIxEAbgc/0VYUBJWncItPQSFgoei9BDT7Ue0pA1A26UJKIg/vat7hLprgXnkI835CETU6yMaRpSxunwWPF2iuJYbQKnMqawtp5HoagoJpO4oGXx8qqECjbtgmfxidSpqTV5Lo6jh20gnyoO48guVZZsHL89TNk5c4TpkID1SkwZXGOhhkIGWCsYHcImYW1rC30hR/eEvdMJkSJicpexorWFVmhX/wjX@6wT8EdHFwzcdpEPBsIfoBM@pZy/@ed3/fGFTu5ni6WDTsi72y76P6lX1ieUUsLwDTk7C6fmFw).

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##hc5NC8IwDAbgs/6KEhmssIWCIoIMBI8iePDkx6F23VpwVdbCBuJvn3NSQYXZQ0je8JCKOBeiaUapzLSRJAstLbVJZR3aaDKlTcG1CeltOLi2sctCCOKZJUlCAnswELUAlEZXOyAfj0YE3jGd93nBy/LisJCFhE/vo35fKe4QtUV06lkzfZbQ@a776/HErSoF/P7fL/r9lrH1woxXfLNDxarl/qjg5f3U73kujUPGGHzf91nr780D "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Cheddar, 16 bytes

```
@.sub(/.*\./,"")
```

simple regex solution. Alternative solution using split:

```
@.split('.')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```ruby
->s{s[/[^.]+$/]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ujhaPzpOL1ZbRT@29n9BaUmxQlq0UnJiUVF@iV5uam6qUiwXTFQvKbE4oygZSSTEwMDXIc/YOzEgSi/DoNw5OjYDSTYnP0cpVkFZoTQvJTUtMy81RSEpNSOxLDO/tOg/AA)

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeViU@Wj86Ti9WW0U/9v//5MSiovwSvdzU3FQuvaTE4oyiZK4QAwNfhzxj78SAKL0Mg3Ln6NgMrpz8nH/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA "Ruby – Try It Online") with `-p`

Comment: or, [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AlPlo/Ok6PK1ZbRT/2///kxKKi/BK93NTcVC69pMTijKJkrhADA1@HPGPvxIAovQyDcufo2AyunPycf/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA "Ruby – Try It Online") if `"..."` are acceptable :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
I..ï⁾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/31NP7/D6R437/v8vz0gs0dPLLNbTK8kAkWmZOakA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 8 bytes

**7 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
s;.*\.;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcu7CgIxEAXQfj5F8DIgVtssWIpgYeWjyC6jE8iLZGD1540sNqc7RWrY994GbO4YelcPexvNrtZsiBKFQg60qDPAN8B09emDECbXtM50YT6NaXd05yuUl8PtoeRekgzMTBKLfUDr@LdvLuZzan1bfg)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 58 bytes

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 29 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input via cell `[A1]` and outputs to the console. Return string is of the form `.Extension`.

```vb
?Mid([A1],InStrRev([A1],"."))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 34 bytes

A [basic](/questions/tagged/basic) answer

Takes input as a string from STDIN, and outputs of the form `.Extension` to STDOUT.

```vb
Input""s$
?Mid$(s$,RInStr(s$,"."))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESalYhcveNzNFRaNYRSfIMy@4pAjEUtJT0tT8/9@3Us8tMydVzz8nRS8ktbhErzIxCQA)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 25 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs the detected file extension of the form `Extension` to the calling cell.

```
=RegexExtract(A1,"[^\.]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

### ><>, 50 bytes

```
i:0( ?v
v[:<2~<
r  ^]+1r<
>:"."=?v^
v?l<r~r<;
>o ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQEPBvoyrLNrKxqjOhqtIQSEuVtuwyIbLzkpJT8nWviyOq8w@x6aorsjGmssuXyHu//8QAwNfhzxj78SAKL0Mg3Ln6NgMAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ActionScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) [2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#ActionScript_2.0), 42 bytes

```
function a(b){trace(b.split(".").pop());};
```

Technically the ;s aren't required for it to *compile*, at least in JPEXS, but it's good practice. Call:

```
a("a.b");
```

(traces "b")

Comment: Oh, OK. Looking at other examples, I didn't realise that. ActionScript doesn't really *have* a way to take inputs, so sure, delete this. Unless...

Comment: Looks good. Happy golfing.

Comment: Awesome. By the way, putting the trace() inside the function is shorter when considering outputting, but then it requires a string be included when calling the function - is that allowed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by it requiring a string to be included when calling the function as I hardly know any Actionscript. In general it's allowed to mix and match any of the default allowed input and output methods.

Comment: function a(b){trace(b.split(".").pop());}; prints the output and is only 42 bytes, but calling the function would be a("a.b");
ActionScript has syntax very similar to JavaScript, so you can pretty much just read it like JavaScript.

Comment: If that is valid Actionscript then I think that would be fine. The only thing is that it is not actually shorter (nor is it longer) than what you currently have so you can use whichever you like without an impact on your score.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74275/discussion-between-jhynjhiruu-rekrap-and-0).

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
q'./W=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v1BdTz/c9v//5MSiovwSvdzU3FQA)

```
        Print
    W     the last
     =    element
   /      of the result of splitting
q         the input
 '.       on the character '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 9 bytes

```
L,"."$tbU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR0lPSaUkKfS/i05yYk6OjoOOYSwXl4tOSmZxQU5ipY6VDpcCECiVpBaX6JVUlChBuOUZiSV6epnFenolGSAyLTMnFSoVYmDg65Bn7J0YEKWXYVDuHB2bAZXRS0oszihKhvCcYlPCkkLBzEdNa6pBltc6xYL5pgpKCrp2CkoRYJ67g1MySEmSdh4XlwrUXf//6@qWlqQBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 6 bytes

```
r'.:Qp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//79IXc8qsOD//4xMvZKKEgA)

```
r       grabs input as string
 '.     literal period
   :    split string on period
    Q   grap bottom item
     p  print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 18 bytes

```
i:0(6$.:"."=?]
ro|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMNMRc9KSU/J1j6Wqyi/5v//8ozEEj29zGI9vZIMEJmWmZMKAA)

#### How It Works:

```
i:(6$.  Jump to the second line if out of input
      :"."=  Else check if the character is a .
           ?[ And create a new stack if it is
              Loop back to the beginning of the line
If it is end of input
ro|  Reverse the current stack once and output, erroring on the EOF (-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
'./H
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%27.%2FH&i=hi.txt%0Acarrot.meme%0Alol%0Awhat..is..this..file%0A.bashrc%0AT00M%40n3KaPZ.h0wC%5B%5Dh%0Aagent.000&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

Split on `.`, take last part.

Answer (score 1):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), 48 bytes

```
SELECT RIGHT(F,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(F))) FROM T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f5820/2)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 46 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
S	I '.' REM . I	:S(S)
	OUTPUT =I
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hCsYyFTXU1cIcvVV0FPw5LQK1gjW5OL0Dw0BygIVcbn6ufz/7wgEeiAQEhECAA)

Takes the input, then repeatedly replaces it with all the text following the first `.` until no `.`s remain, then outputs the value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 26 bytes

```
s=>(k=s::split".")[(#k)-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7v9jWTiPbttjKqrggJ7NESU9JM1pDOVtT1zD2f0FRZl6JRpqGUklGZrFeRmpeTr5eeX5RToqSpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jotlin](https://github.com/jrtapsell/jotlin), 17 bytes

```
split(".").last()
```

Full file:

```
data class Test(val input: String, val output: String)

val test = listOf(
        Test("hi.txt", "txt"),
        Test("carrot.meme", "meme"),
        Test("what..is..this..file", "file"),
        Test(".bashrc", "bashrc"),
        Test("T00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h", "h0wC[]h"),
        Test("agent.000", "000")
)

fun String.f() = split(".").last()

for ((i, o) in test) {
    if (o != i.f()) {
        throw AssertionError()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 26 bytes

-14 bytes thanks to J.Doe

```r
sub("^.*[.]","",scan(,""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYqxCsIwGIT3PsY/JVKPgKuC4CgFBydLhTQ0JmBTSP7Sgvjs0VJxOb777mK2@60dg2E/BDHLVzI6HP4CgJxzGltBd2xqNFQSlctHfEHK/C4KK8h58MwkFzY6xoHRd323islpBnwC2C1p/fO3oNXJRbOWq1LVMezO@nKDU9Opbtw66EcXGEopkvkD)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYqxCsIwGIT3PsY/JVKPgKuC4CgFBydLhTQ0JmBTSP7Sgvjs0VJxOb777mK2@60dg2E/BDHLVzI6HP4CgJxzGltBd2xqNFQSlctHfEHK/C4KK8h58MwkFzY6xoHRd323islpBnwC2C1p/fO3oNXJRbOWq1LVMezO@nKDU9Opbtw66EcXGEopkvkD "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 129 bytes

```
1 INPUT F$:F=INSTR(F$,"."):IF F=0 THEN END
2 FOR I=LEN(F$) TO 1 STEP -1:P$=MID$(F$,I,1):O$=P$+O$:IF P$="." THEN PRINT O$:END
3 NEXT
```

**Explanation**

Get a filename. If it doesn't contain a period, bail out.
Otherwise, collect letters from right to left to build an output string.
When we see a period, print the string.

**Output**

```
? hi.txt
.txt

? .bashrc
.bashrc

? T00M@n3KaPZ.h0wC[]h
.h0wC[]h
```

Answer (score 1):

## Red 9 bytes

```
Suffix? f
```

Assumes file is is in word 'f

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation or interpreters for that language?

Comment: I don't think this does what the challenge asks.  The challenge is asking for a program that takes the file name and gives the extension.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 48 bytes

```
rEeeEeEEEeREEeREEEerEEREEEEEEEreererEEEEeEeereee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!98T!pEE7*$RsG)

Answer (score 1):

### Emacs, 6 bytes

The cursor needs to be at the start of the line containing the string.

This will delete the entire line if there's no extension.

```
C-<SPC> C-e C-r . <RET> <BACKSPACE>
```

Explanation:

```
C-<SPC>      start a selection
C-e          go to the end of the line
C-r . <RET>  search for "." backward
<BACKSPACE>  delete the selected text (which should be the text before the last ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 13 bytes

```
K46-$v;F@46+"
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/bxExXpczazcHETFvp////ShmpOTn5eiWpxSV6emmZOalKAA)**

```
               \ Implicit: string on stack as character codes
K46-           \ Subtract 46 from each code point, mapping '.' to 0
    $v;        \ While the top of stack is non-zero, move to auxiliary stack
       F       \ Copy auxiliary stack onto main stack
        @      \ Reverse (to obtain original order)
         46+   \ Add 46 (to obtain original characters)
            "  \ Print as a string.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 76 bytes

```
{((((([()()()]){}){}){}()){}{}<>)<>}<>{({}(((()()()()()){}()){}()){}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1oDBKI1NEEwVrO6FoI0NIFEda2NnaaNHZCs1gAKAYEmDMKUgAmYqv//S1KLS/TSMquq9KoyC/7rJgMA)

Explanation:

```
{          loop over stack
  (                            push
    (((([()()()]){}){}){}()){} -46
  {}                           plus the top of the stack
  <>)                          to the other side
<>}        retuen for more

<>      on the other side...

{       loop until 0
  (                             push
     {}                         the top of the stack
     (((()()()()()){}()){}()){} +46
  <>)                           to the first side
<>}       return for more

<> print the first side
```

6 bytes less than the [other Brain-Flack solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120943/31203).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
@R:a^"."
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJAUjphXlwiLlwiIiwiIiwiYWJjLnh5eiIsIi1wIl0=)

-2 from emanresu A.

Comment: This can be 8 bytes - [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJAUjphXlwiLlwiIiwiIiwiYWJjLnh5eiIsIi1wIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hd`, 4 bytes

```
\./÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/Rk//8Pb//8szEkv09DKL9fRKMkBkWmZO6n/djBQA)

Splits on dots, and prints the last element.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 14 bytes

```
:l
s/.\././
tl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/3yqHq1hfL0ZPX0@fqyTn///cxMw8PSAoqAQA)

Just repeatedly removes the character before a `.` until there's none left.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 14 bytes

```
file-extension
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5BCsIwELz3FfsBl4A3vQgeREQR1IulhzWsJtgmbbLSgvj2mkZwD7Mzywyzd9Liw3g5bQ@bBViPLYlx1HCErofI3YudTuLJwXENbeDITpIRlkXR9e8C0hiLMkimmkLwgg03nHXt67x7Q4JoI6KYCe@2/hnwRtEEnflZqf3KzXd0vKJR/bqsTL7TI3WiUqr4QDlO0RkPwi5a78YKyv9bbbAJK9C@aX1kYNJm/AI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 24 bytes

```arturo
$[s]->last split.by:"."s
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?1oRzQC)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 25 bytes

```python
lambda f:f.split('.')[-1]
```

Everyone probably knows this works, so I'm not gonna put a TIO link.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120935/114446)

Comment: Still, counts towards Python THREE, not Python TWO

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 12 bytes

```
m/.<-[.]>*$/
```

14 to make it a callable block:

```
{m/.<-[.]>*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/gguqljm6us)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 7 bytes

```sh
<<<$1:e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRsXQKvV/LVeaQkamXklFCZCRnFhUlF@il5uamwrk5eTnAMnyjMQSPb3MYj29kgwQmZaZA5LUS0oszihKBrKUQgwMfB3yjL0TA6L0MgzKnaNjM5SA4onpqXklegYGBv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'./
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UolS7IKlpSVpuhaL1fX0lxQnJRdD-Qu2lGcklujpZRbr6ZVkgMi0zJxUiBwA)

##### Explanation

```
'./  # Implicit input
  /  # Split the input on
'.   # The "." character
     # Implicit output of last item
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```
{it.substring(it.lastIndexOf(".")+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/J@SmqaQqGCr8L86s0SvuDSpuKQoMy9dA8jJSSwu8cxLSa3wT9NQ0lPS1DbUrP1fAJQtUUjUUMpIzcnJ1yvPL8pJ0SupKFHS/A8A)

Comment: How did someone already upvote this lol. Literally 1 second after I hit submit it hit +1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->f{f.split('.')[-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfaPtf1y6tOk2vuCAns0RDXU9dM1rXMLb2f0FpSbFGol5yYk6OhlJGak5Ovl55flFOil5JRYmSpuZ/AA)

## **12 bytes**

```ruby
File.extname
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 21 bytes

```
puts [file ext $argv]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6LTMnVSG1okRBJbEovSz2////yYlFRfklermpuakA)

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 22 bytes

```
g(n)=split(n,'.')[end]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 11 bytes

```perl6
{m/\.\w+$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7vzpXP0YvplxbRb/2vzVXWn6Rgk1Gpl5JRYlCQWJmXoleakWqQk5@jl6ygl5SYnFGUbKdQjUXZ3FipYKSSryCLpCXpqASX6tkzVX7HwA)