# Extract filename from path

Tags: code-golf, string, file-system

Given a printable ASCII string representing a path to a file on a POSIX-compliant system, return just the filename, i.e. remove everything until and including the last slash (`/`):

`/full/path/file.name.ext` → `file.name.ext`

`nopath.here` → `nopath.here`

`dir/.hidden` → `.hidden`

`/dirs.can/have.exts/file` → `file`

`./here` → `here`

`don't\do this` → `don't\do this`

Comment: I‘m just curious to see how this is done in a variety of languages...ie whether there‘s any jumping through hoops or if is built-in. Can you suggest a better way to find that out?

Comment: There is [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120925/whats-the-file-extension?rq=1), although not exactly a dupe.

Comment: Now, I doubt that there is any difference between this and the "what's the file extension" challenge, as they're just "shortest substring after a `<'.' or '/', depends on the challenge`".

Comment: @user202729 Right, I'm kind of awaiting it to be re-opened so I can dupe-hammer it.

Answer (score 3):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 4 bytes

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 4 bytes

```apl
.*/
```

[Try QuadR online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BDcIwDEXvniI3JA72Qlys2pUjhaQkKWICBmBEFglgVRW92e99/X9bWeoYeCYYg@Y1JVq4G80xKWa@Kuqjh/fzFQ4EIJdfDk2ruv77ASRWQosiml1uNwB9TcOJMxnfvan51L4AgLR3bmUln/pFSugWm/MD@QA)

[Try Retina online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BDcIwDEXvniI3pB5ssQ8Xi7iKpeBUiUFMwACMyCKhRFVFb/Z7X/9XcTU@944TQe8033OmhT3RrFnQ@CYoTw@f1zscCICVXw6TVBn67weIWgmTxig25HYD0GoaXtko8WM0tTG1LwAg7Z1bWbGTX2IJnrQNfiBf)

Replace as many characters as possible, followed by a slash, with nothing.

Equivalent to the 9-byte Dyalog APL function `'.*/'⎕R''`.

Comment: Also works in Retina.

Comment: @Emigna Thanks, added.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>41</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.split('/')[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcwxDgIhEIXh3lOQbZDCmWhp4klci1EgkLADWWaNnh7XLQyx/d7LX94SMp@av4wt0XS3pOq5Qi0pyl6jNtfD8dbKHFmUX8EvKWEhCehjcsA0OXAv0Wb3@3D@7hDc7Hq2cUYI0VrHPePqFR7EGOi5teqW7j@Af7HBZtYy2qwkxDqY9gE)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
'/¡θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvlfXf/QwnM7/lcqHd6voGuncHi/ks5//bTSnBz9gsSSDP20zJxUvbzE3FS91IoSrrx8kKBeRmpRKldKZpG@XkZmSkpqHpc@kFOsl5yYp5@RWAZWWgzWyaWnD1Gbn6deEpOSr1CSkVkMAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 25 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll(".*/","")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xboMwEIZ3nuLkJRAl57mijdSlW6aMTYcrNsHE2JZ9oEZVnp0Swl6mk@7@77u/pYH2PmjXquvLaLrgI0M7LbFnY7HuXcXGO9yWWWUpJTiScfCbASQmNhV8LInXE0fjLrvnOEANb2PaHxJGHSxV@t3aXOBWip0QxVhOgtB/20mweAZvFHQPef5UfH4BxUsq5mcAp1ti3aHvGcN0ZuvyGikEe8uFrHtrZSBuZG2sRkedRv3DoijKf2HnHyA2OupVeWWixMYopd2qvJyAhBU52dAw10pzy1UwyvW9vNvw@aw8cGPSgtyz@/gH)

#### Honorable mention

26 bytes:

```java
s->("/"+s).split(".*/")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 24 bytes

```
func[s][last split s"/"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxCgMhEEV7TyHbpHP6HCOtsZCdEQUziuOGQNizm80WQdL84v3Ha4TjRqitU@E6wsarFWezl66l5nTsAosbtSXuOug3hC1nqL5HCCmTYf8gQ6@@q5/C5XubSI0miqmBiQmReKJwYDGrZ4j@eYbk7E6Kgf9S4Uu/Y9E9JtnV@AA)

Red has a built-in `split-path` but it needs a path agrument and not a string.

`f: func[p][last split-path to-file p]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
'//H
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%27%2F%2FH&i=%2Ffull%2Fpath%2Ffile.name.ext%0Anopath.here%0Adir%2F.hidden%0A%2Fdirs.can%2Fhave.exts%2Ffile%0A.%2Fhere%0Adon%27t%5Cdo+this&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

Split on "/", take last part.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 12 bytes

A built-in.

```
FileNameTake
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBDsIgEER/ZUMTvVT2CzSePBoP3toeNmUJRKANoDExfjtCDx7fzLzxlA17ynamouFYLtbxlTzf6cHlFm3IQ9eDgMMJRA966KYJdoBn@AjUT@dwrQeoqyVD1SS/c92JsLRcGo7cUNmI0lilODTEyknOFNDQa3PSdtE6iX9pCfs8jmqBbGwS3/ID)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
r.fst.span(/='/').r
r=reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAva@wUCXagfgF@UG3rl0MigGRJpZt@nzcu43sKLUG509oYvNkQu2BecTxmfSmWcuvqJX40t4gg5z@dn01uAPDgEK@oXfk3nEmHeJauNJqMS0ifw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 19 bytes

```
n->n.split('/')[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5RCsMgEESvIqFgAs0uPUBzkTQfElcUzCpxU/rRu9sY@vlmeMOsaU18SHXPV@VxYig5Buk16mEeH0udNbojRsxGPLoQCdhsBPQRfVeaU8vB004NbdgRfLCWuCGeXGA1jN68L6dcE60D/EudTazlZZMSH0q3qO@kNpNvfd4DC4AbWnKeLMdG9Qc)